# jquery UI date range picker error "Cannot read "property" left of null"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I am using the jquery ui date range picker for rails 3.1. I have managed to get this to work but when I try to use any jquery inside any of the view files, I get this error(see it from console) that says "daterangepicker.jQuery.js:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of null".

```
var rangeInput = jQuery(this);

var options = jQuery.extend({
...
posX: rangeInput.offset().left,
...
})
```

The line which is in question is:

```
posX: rangeInput.offset().left, // x position
```

However, my theory is that the source of the problem stems from the beginning, where rangeInput is defined in this line:

```
var rangeInput = jQuery(this);
```

Maybe this is being called before I actually pick dates which is why the error is coming and why it seems to stop my jquery from running? Thanks for any help.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any "target" argument to JQuery.extend().  Is that just because of how you truncated your code?

Comment: Also, what code is calling this code segment?  What is $(this) in this situation?

Comment: Sorry Dave, $(this) is to refer to I assume my text box where the plugin runs. Another strange issue is that if the plugin is being used on a view, the error disappears. Did not notice that until recently. But that would mean for me to use jquery on a page I would have to include a hidden tag with the daterangepicker...

Comment: Okay, so, you can add the code that encloses this code segment, which will make it clear what $(this) is?  (I agree with the solution below, it sounds like $(this) is empty, which would result in offset() being null.)

Comment: @Dave thanks for the help. The solution below is right in that it is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logging the value of `rangeInput` to see if it is an empty jQuery object. That would make sense because `jQuery().offset().left` would throw the error you're getting.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You were right on. I didn't think of just checking to see if it was empty, now it is a simple if else statement. Thanks again!